# WSO2 PayloadFactory mediator empty arguments

Tags: wso2, payload, mediator, wso2-esb

in my WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 i have configured this proxy:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SendingByJmsAddressProxy"
     transports="https,http"
     statistics="disable"
     trace="disable"
     startOnLoad="true">
 <target>
    <inSequence>
       <send>
          <endpoint>
             <address uri="http://localhost:8080/RestService/rest/servizio"/>
          </endpoint>
       </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
       <log>
          <property name="codice" expression="//codice"/>
       </log>
       <log level="full"/>
       <switch source="//codice">
          <case regex="asd">
             <send/>
          </case>
          <case regex="0">
             <log>
                <property name="codice" value="check1"/>
             </log>
             <send/>
             <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                   <code>$1</code>
                </format>
                <args>
                   <arg xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" evaluator="xml"
                        expression="//codice"/>
                </args>
             </payloadFactory>
             <property name="messageType" value="application/xml"/>
             <log level="full"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <address uri="jms:/testQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </case>
       </switch>
    </outSequence>
 </target>
 <description/>
</proxy>
```

In the inSequence i forward the client's request to a Rest Service whose response is a json string that looks like this:

```
{
  "codice":"0",
  "messaggio":"Operazione effettuata 18:12",
  "path":"\/path\/1AASSCOGNOME_NOME.111.2231\/",
  "documenti":[{
            "idAggregatoContenitore":"3508",
            "idDocumento":"016601",
            "idVersione":"17010",
            "numVersione":"1",
            "tipoDocumento":"Documento",
            "autore":"sysadmin",
            "titolo":"prova1",
            "fileName":"FStandard.xml",
            "checkedOut":"false",
            "idDocumentoPadre":"",
            "flagAllegati":"false",
            "flagDaProtocollare":"true",
            "dataCreazione":"11\/02\/2013 19:05",
            "dataChekin":"11\/02\/2013 19:05",
            "mimeType":"text\/xml",
            "empty":"false",
            "data":"1660100000",
            "cache":"false",
            "tipo":"D",
            "nome":"prova1",
            "keyData":"16601",
            "keyNome":"prova1",
            "keyNumero":"",
            "keyTipo":"D",
            "fileExtension":"path\/xml_file.png",
            "evidenza":"false",
            "originalDocumentoPadreId":"",
            "originalDocumentoId":"016601",
            "originalAggregatoContenitoreId":"3508"
          },
          {
            "idAggregatoContenitore":"3508",
            "idDocumento":"016602",
            "idVersione":"17011",
            "numVersione":"1",
            "tipoDocumento":"Documento",
            "autore":"sysadmin",
            "titolo":"123456789",
            "fileName":"HTTP Proxy Server.jmx",
            "checkedOut":"false",
            "idDocumentoPadre":"",
            "flagAllegati":"false",
            "flagDaProtocollare":"true",
            "dataCreazione":"11\/02\/2013 19:19",
            "dataChekin":"11\/02\/2013 19:19",
            "mimeType":"application\/octet-stream",
            "empty":"false",
            "data":"1660200000",
            "cache":"false",
            "tipo":"D",
            "nome":"123456789",
            "keyData":"16602",
            "keyNome":"123456789",
            "keyNumero":"",
            "keyTipo":"D",
            "fileExtension":"path\/Documento.png",
            "evidenza":"false",
            "originalDocumentoPadreId":"",
            "originalDocumentoId":"016602",
            "originalAggregatoContenitoreId":"3508"
          }],
  "data":"350800000",
  "tipoAggregatoEnum":"R",
  "statoEnum":"aperto",
  "keyData":"1360602720000",
  "keyNome":"1aasscognome_nome.111.2231",
  "nomeAggregatoNoNumero":"1AASSCOGNOME_NOME.111.2231",
  "keyNumero":"1AASSCOGNOME_NOME.111.2231",
  "keyTipo":"R",
  "originalAggregatoId":"3508",
  "originalAggregatoPadre":"3108"
}
```

As standard behaviour ESB converts the incoming json message into an xml formatted message.
Now in the outSequence i want:

1)sending back the RestService response to the client: by the  mediator

2)then i want to build an xml message extracting some elements from the message payload and then to send it by jms protocol elsewhere.

The proxy works fine all but the PayloadFactory mediator. Indeed the message built by the Payload Factory mediator has its body empty:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<Body>
  <code xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
</Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

could anyone tell me why the specified arg tag is empty (the xpath expression seems to be correct)? what's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i've solved.
In the outsequence i need to send two message: the first by a simple

```
<send/>
```

should have to return the service's response to the calling client.  After this i need to send a second message to elsewhere. In the code above i used another send mediator... but it seems that the first one ()  empties the message payload, so the arg expressions are consequently empty.
Using the clone mediator i solved the problem:

```
<outSequence>
     <log>
        <property name="codice" expression="//codice"/>
     </log>
     <log level="full"/>
     <switch source="//codice">
        <case regex="asd">
           <send/>
        </case>
        <case regex="0">
           <log>
              <property name="codice" value="check1"/>
           </log>
           <clone>
              <target>
                 <sequence>
                    <send/>
                 </sequence>
              </target>
              <target>
                 <sequence>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                       <format>
                          <messaggio>$1</messaggio>
                       </format>
                       <args>
                          <arg xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" evaluator="xml"
                               expression="//messaggio"/>
                       </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <property name="messageType" value="application/xml"/>
                    <log level="full"/>
                    <send>
                       <endpoint>
                          <address uri="jms:/NuovoEvento?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties&transport.jms.DestinationType=topic"/>
                       </endpoint>
                    </send>
                 </sequence>
              </target>
           </clone>
        </case>
     </switch>
  </outSequence>
```